# angular controller only picks up the input values changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a fairly simple angular controller method :

```
$scope.addComment = function () {
        if ($scope.newComment.message) {
          $scope.can_add_comments = false;
          new Comments({ comment: $scope.newComment }).$save(function (comment) {
            $scope.comments.unshift(comment);
            return $scope.can_add_comments = true;
          });
          return $scope.newComment = {};
        }
      };
```

And in my form I have a textarea that holds the value of comment :

```
<textarea class="required" cols="40" id="new_comment_message" maxlength="2500" ng-disabled="!can_add_comments" ng-model="newComment.message" required="required" rows="20"></textarea>
```

Works great so far, however I do want to send some data, hidden data with the comment as well. So I added something to hold that value :

```
<input id="hash_id" name="hash_id" ng-init="__1515604539_122642" ng-model="newComment.hash_id" type="hidden" value="__1515604539_122642">
```

However when I inspect the `$scope.newComment` it always comes back as an object with only message as it's property, which is the value from the text area, and I don't get the property on the object `hash_id`.

When I make this input non hidden and I manually type in the value into the input field and submit a form, I do get a object with `hash_id` property. What am I doing wrong here, not setting it right?

Comment: what are the properties in newComment? It sounds like you dont have hash_id on newComment. When you manually edit it, angular adds  ( newComment['hash_id'] = newValue) . can you do a jsfiddle?

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy By manually I mean when I type in the input field and press the submit

Comment: `<input id="hash_id" name="hash_id" ng-model="newComment.hash_id" type="hidden" ng-value="__1515604539_122642">`
 May work

Comment: @ODelibalta doesn't work also without ng-init and with just ng-value

Comment: I am not sure what to do the way you want to do. Since you are initializing a value to a variable in your scope, I think you should make that in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `ng-model` doesn't use the `value` property as a "default" (i.e. it won't copy it back into your model). If you want a default, it should be placed wherever the model is defined:

`$scope.newComment = { hash_id: "__1515604539_122642", /* Other params */ };`

Alternatively, changing the `ng-init` to an assignment should work (though I would recommend  the above solution instead):

`<input id="hash_id" name="hash_id" ng-init="newComment.hash_id = '__1515604539_122642'" ng-model="newComment.hash_id" type="hidden">`

Comment: I'd say this is pretty spot on, although I am curious as to why init is being used in the first place.

Comment: Given that init has the same value as the `value` property, my guess is that the OP was hoping it would assign its value as the initial value for the model.